# CATransition as an explicit animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, catransition

Greetings to all.

Does anyone know if it is possible to essentially convert `CATransition` to an explicit animation? That is, I almost want it to behave like `CABasicAnimation` does- I need to be able to create the `CATransition` object, set the options for it (`duration`, `timingFunction`, `delegate`, `type`, `fillMode`, `removedOnCompletion`, etc)- then essentially store it for later use and make sure it isn't trying to animate stuff that's happening between the `CATransition` object creation and the point in time at which I actually need it to animate a set of properties.

If I'm using `CABasicAnimation`, I can easily do this as nothing is animated until the animation is added to the layer and only the property specified in `animationWithKeyPath` is animated between toValue/fromValue. However, `CATransition` apparently fires `[CATransaction begin]` the moment you create the animation object for capturing property changes.

What I need to be able to do (as per above) is create the `CATransition` object, set the above options, then put it away until I actually need to use it- at which point I'll change the actual properties that it needs to animate, then add it to the appropriate `CALayer` via `addAnimation`.

Does anyone know how to do this safely?

PS: The reason for this is because my application depends heavily on a custom animation queueing system that handles animation dependencies. For example, certain things need to animate before an orientation change occurs, so I can queue ~10 animations which will all fire off AND the orientation change animation object as well- but the orientation change animation won't fire until the previous animations that it depends on have finished. Incidentally, `CABasicAnimation` can be wrapped up nicely into a queued animation object class. `CATransition` seems to be a bit of a different beast, hence the above question- I need to be able to safely create an animation queue object, setup a bunch of `CATransition` options, queue it up, then actually have it execute later on (meanwhile all sorts of stuff is happening) when all of it's dependencies have been satisfied (in this case, `CATransition` is being used for the orientation change animation).

Thanks,
-Keven Tipping